# Does there exists "3 state" relay switch, with 3 input pins?

Tags: switches, relay

Normally relay has 5 pins: 2 control pin (signal and ground), 2 input pins, and 1 output. If there is voltage on control pin relative to grounded pin output is connected to first pin, if there is no - to second.

I wonder does there exists relay with 6 pins and 3 inputs, so that

```
- if positive voltage presents on control pin => output is connected to first input
- if no voltage (grounded) => output to second input
- if negative voltage => output to third
```

Comment: http://www.ansaldo-sts.com/sites/ansaldosts/files/manuali-ansaldo/CatalogCutSheets/RSE-4E3_PN-150BD.pdf

Comment: a relay is an electrically operated switch. there is no input pin or output pin. there are just mechanical contacts that short pins together, same as if you touch wires together using your hands.

Comment: jsotola, sure. i mean when using it as a logic gate you would end up with logical inputs and logical output

Answer (score 4):

It's really more like two relays in one case, but this Panasonic part is similar to what you are requesting:

[image]

You could wire the coils with diodes to do what you specifically request.

Comment: but is it possible to do with a single coil design?

Comment: @xakepp35 Probably, using a permanent magnet, but I really doubt there is a significant enough market for such a thing to be manufactured in modern times.